# reassign a python function via __call__ to use another function

Tags: python, function, monkeypatching

I tried to do some extreme monkey patching and got unexpected results.
I reassigned the `__call__` method of a function to point a different function.

I expected to change the behavior of the function, however it seems like it retained its original function.

- Isn't the class `function` a subclass of `object` or, is it some "exotic" `object` ?
- does it override the `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__` dunder methods?

*Note*: I am aware that simply reassigning the name of the original function to the new function will achieve the desired results. my question is about the inner workings of the `function` class.

---

**example**

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

def minus(a,b):
    return a-b

add.__call__ = minus
```

when running `add` you can see it retained its original functionality

```
>>> add(1,2)
... 3
```

Comment: magic methods cannot be reasigned

Comment: Technically they can be reassigned; it just doesn't do anything, because Python doesn't call them on instances, only on the type. You'd have to change the `__call__` of the function type, which 1) isn't possible and 2) would affect all functions.

Comment: after some additional thinking, the thing i need to do is `add.__class__.__call__ = minus`. however I get `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'function'`. ohh well, Thanks !! guess I will have to use [forbiddenfruit](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit)